# How to make macro runs faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I was just wondering if I could speed up this macro?

```
`Columns("O:O").Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
Columns("N:O").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp`
```

I only want it to run to Row# 26 but when I tries to change it to `O:O26` or `N2:O26`. I get error either "400" or "Type Mismatch".

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: `column` by default runs over the whole column. If you want to run it over a specific range of cells, use `Range("O1:O26")`

Comment: It is understood that you want to delete rows in `N:O`. It is unclear which ones you want to delete. There are three possibilities: 1.) the rows that have empty cells in column `O` no matter what is in column `N`, 2.) the rows that have empty cells in both columns (*AND*), 3.) the rows that have empty cells in either column (*OR*). Since you have gone through all the trouble with `Replace`, I would guess it's the first option but I can't be sure. Your code though is implying the 3rd option but it will fail because the range will have some cells from either column which you cannot delete.

Comment: There is, of course, a workaround for the third option. You might think about what I am talking about since there are no issues when applying your code to the whole column. That is because in your data there is no row that is empty in column `N` but not empty in column `O` and vice versa. Let us know which option you're aiming for and we'll probably have a solution for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Delete Rows (Cells)

[image]

**The Beginning**

```vb
Sub TheBeginning()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim fCell As Range: Set fCell = ws.Range("O2")
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = ws.Range(fCell, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, fCell.Column).End(xlUp))

    ' Empty the cells containing zeros.        
    rg.Replace What:="0", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

    ' add the code of the preferred option here...

End Sub
```

**Option 1**

[image]

- Delete rows of empty cells in column `O` no matter what's in column `N`.

```vb
Sub Option1()
    
    ' Delete rows of empty cells in column 'O' no matter what's in column 'N'.
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
        Set vrg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Union(vrg.Offset(, -1), vrg)
    
    drg.Select ' .Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub
```

**Option 2**

[image]

- Delete rows of empty cells in columns `N` **AND** `O`.

```vb
Sub Option2()
    
    ' Delete rows of empty cells in columns 'N' AND 'O'.
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Union(rg.Offset(, -1), rg)
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim ivrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
        Set ivrg = Intersect(drg, Intersect(vrg, drg.Columns(1)).EntireRow, _
            Intersect(vrg, drg.Columns(2)).EntireRow)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If ivrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ivrg.Select ' .Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub
```

**Option 3 Wrong**

[image]

- Delete rows of empty cells in columns `N` **OR** `O` (WRONG). I tagged it wrong because it will delete cells in each column independently and I consider it highly unlikely that's what is needed although it is a valid option.

```vb
Sub Option3Wrong()
    
    ' Delete rows of empty cells in columns 'N' OR 'O' (WRONG).
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Union(rg.Offset(, -1), rg)
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    vrg.Select ' .Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub
```

**Option 3**

[image]

- Delete rows of empty cells in columns `N` **OR** `O`.

```vb
Sub Option3()
    
    ' Delete rows of empty cells in columns 'N' OR 'O'.
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Union(rg.Offset(, -1), rg)
    
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no cells
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Set vrg = Intersect(vrg.EntireRow, drg)
    
    vrg.Select ' .Delete xlShiftUp
    
End Sub
```

**Tips**

- Note how the *ISBLANK* columns get all messed up after the cells get shifted. That is something to keep in mind when not deleting entire rows.
- When developing a code that deletes, it is advisable to use `Select` instead of `Delete`. Of course, you need to keep in mind that the worksheet needs to be active to be able to use it in this simple form. You can improve it with:

  ```
  If not wb Is ActiveWorkbook Then wb.Activate
  If Not ws Is ActiveSheet Then ws.Select
  ```